# How do I equip a customized weapon?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've customized a few weapons, but can't seem to find how to use them - Selecting my equipment on the Sortie Prep section only seems to let me pick the default versions.

Comment: Be sure you didn't accidentally cancel your customizations when you made them; you have to select the "OK" menu option at the bottom to save your customizations. Leaving the menu any other way will not save your changes (or the loadout you just made if it didn't exist before).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The customized weapon appears as a separate item, at the bottom of the weapon list, and is coloured yellow instead of white.